# Animation Scrolling Issue

Tags: reactjs

While opening the page it doesn't show the content, after scrolling down and coming up only it shows the content. I added [https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-animate-on-scrol](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-animate-on-scroll)l this package for animation.

```
  <ScrollAnimation animateIn="fadeInUp" animateOnce={true} delay={100}>
    <h2 className="commonheading">
      Sell your home appliances and furniture in{" "}
      <span>3 Steps process</span>
    </h2>
    <p className="commonpara">
      Book a free pick from anywhere in the UAE at your convenience and get
      instant cash
    </p>
  </ScrollAnimation>
```

First, it shows like this
[First image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IWjtD.png)

After Scroll down and coming up it shows the content
[Second image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7d0Bk.png)

What should I do now? My Requirement is if the content appears it will automatically animate without scrolling

**It's a component it will be used in multiple pages so can't remove the ScrollAnimation**

Comment: Well if you need no scroll to show your component then just remove the ScrollAnimation and use some setTimeout with some state to make it appear shortly after loading into the website?

Comment: "My Requirement is if the content appears it will automatically animate without scrolling." If you want to automatically animate without scrolling, why are you using a scroll animation?

Comment: if the element is already in the viewport, why do you want it to appear on scroll?

Comment: It's a component it will be used on multiple pages. when its viewport its not showing that's my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://michalsnik.github.io/aos/ This package works fine, it doesn't have an invisible problem while scrolling down. If we scroll down normally animation works perfectly on the page.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).